# How to convert Time Picker into 24 Hours format in Swift 3 ?

Tags: ios, time, datepicker, swift3

I have these time picker code below.

I got an output **"1:00 PM"** for example.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var timeTxt: UITextField!
    let time_picker  = UIDatePicker()
    var time: String!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayTime()
    }

    func displayTime(){
        let toolbar_time = UIToolbar()
        toolbar_time.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton_time = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(selectTime))
        toolbar_time.setItems([doneButton_time], animated: false)

        timeTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar_time
        timeTxt.inputView = time_picker
    }

    func selectTime() {

        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short

        timeTxt.text = timeFormatter.string(from: time_picker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

But my goal is to store the time value "1:00 PM" as **(24 hours format) "1300"** as String type into database

I want to get rid of **":"** from **13:00 to "1300** only"

Can someone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with `timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"`?

Comment: is there any way to get rid of semicolon from the time value ? i mean 1:00 into 1300 only, not 13:00 . .

Comment: `let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
timeFormatter.string(from: Date())` works for me

Comment: BTW `"HH:mm a"` is wrong. HH means 00-23. For AM/PM you have to use h or hh. And when using dateFormat property you shouldn't set dateStyle or timeStyle.

Comment: I see . Thanks for the answer :) .. It work

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
timeFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
```

Answer (score -2):

for change time format you goto setting -> general -> Date & Time and enable 24-Hour Time switch it will show 24 hours time format in your date picker

```
func selectTime() {

    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hmm" // set this date format string
    timeTxt.text = timeFormatter.string(from: time_picker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```